# How to simulate one time login and logout actions in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter - performance testing. I want to have and run the scenario in Jmeter when users will login to application once at the start of the run, navigate the steps, screens multiple times throughout the run and then all the users will logout (again once) at the end of the run.

I have used Loadrunner the case mentioned above is implemented easily after placing login action in 'vuser_init', the steps which would be iterated during the run are placed in 'Action' and logout in 'vuser_end' section.

I appreciate your reply.

Regards,
ARAI

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use setup and TearDown Thread Group to perform operation to run **once**, See [example](http://www.testingjournals.com/setup-teardown-thread-group-jmeter/).

> Use of TearDown Thread Group is to differentiate all the post-test actions which are required to run once the execution of normal thread group is over.

You can also use [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

Comment: The link to Once Only Controller is not working anymore.

Comment: @rjose updated link

Comment: Thanks for the updated link. I am looking for One Login, 10 Registration scenario. Should I keep Login request outside the Thread Group ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime Controller and add the steps which you want to run multiple times in your test run to runtime controller and define the time in runtime controller. So you test plan will look like:

Test plan->Thread Group(Loop Count: 1)->Login->Runtime Controller (Add recurring steps to this controller)-> Logout.

With this, your script will Login once and execute steps till the time you have set in runtime controller and then logout once.

Note: you can keep login and logout calls in simple or transaction controller, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Runtime Controller there is a problem.
For example..,

1. You have set 1hr test duration in Runtime Controller
2. Let us assume we got error in action requests then what happens is login step will not get execute and action requests will keep on hitting and all the requests will fail

Thanks,
Usman

Comment: This is feedback for the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627710/7733418 Isn't it?